# Dagger/MissingBinding Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to setup a multi-module Android app using Hilt, but after setting up everything I get the following error:

```
D:\Projetos\historico-de-notificacoes\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\br\com\firstsoft\historiconotificacoes\src\NotificationHistoryApplication_HiltComponents.java:124: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.repository.NotificationRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements NotificationHistoryApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.repository.NotificationRepository is injected at
          br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.usecase.notification.GetRecentNotificationsUseCaseImpl(notificationRepository)
      br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.usecase.notification.GetRecentNotificationsUseCaseImpl is injected at
          br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.usecase.UseCaseModule.bindsGetRecentNotificationsUseCase(arg0)
      br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.domain.src.usecase.notification.GetRecentNotificationsUseCase is injected at
          br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.notifications.recent.RecentViewModel(getRecentNotificationsUseCase)
      br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.notifications.recent.RecentViewModel is injected at
          br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.notifications.recent.RecentViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.NotificationHistoryApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.NotificationHistoryApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? br.com.firstsoft.historiconotificacoes.src.NotificationHistoryApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

I have my code setup like:

`:domain`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Libs.Kotlin.stdLib)

    implementation(Libs.Coroutines.core)

    implementation(Libs.Paging.runtime)

    implementation(Libs.Hilt.core)
    kapt(Libs.Hilt.compiler)
}
```

`:data`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":domain"))

    implementation(Libs.Kotlin.stdLib)

    implementation(Libs.Room.runtime)
    implementation(Libs.Room.ktx)
    kapt(Libs.Room.compiler)

    implementation(Libs.Paging.runtime)

    implementation(Libs.Hilt.core)
    kapt(Libs.Hilt.compiler)

    implementation(Libs.Android.annotation)

    implementation(Libs.Util.gson)
}
```

`:app`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":domain"))

    implementation(Libs.Kotlin.stdLib)

    ...

    implementation(Libs.Hilt.core)
    kapt(Libs.Hilt.compiler)
}
```

Inside `:domain` I have:

```
interface NotificationRepository {}
```

Inside `:data` I have:

```
class NotificationRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val notificationDao: NotificationDao
) : NotificationRepository


@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindsNotificationRepository(impl: NotificationRepositoryImpl): NotificationRepository
}
```

I don't where I messed up but shouldn't this be working? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure about it but your `RepositoryModule` lives in `:data` that is not a dependency in `:app`

Comment: I could solve the problem by implementing `:data` inside `:app` but why's that? I'm kinda new to this kind of dependency inversion and multi-module setups... Do I must always have a module that knows all the others which provides implementations & concepts?

Comment: Not all the others, but only those you use in its scope. Remember that Dagger generates DI graph for you. There's no magic. Your module is installed in application (singleton) therefore `:app` needs to know classes it will depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here was to implement `:data` inside `:app`.

In this specific scenario where we have only these 3 modules, `:app`, `:data` and `:domain`, there has to be a module that aggregates the others, which is this case is the `:app`.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at some examples and comments of this question. I solve this problem just by implementing the *data* module and the *domain* module into my *app* module :)

But this is not what I was thinking of. So just implement modules in the *app* module in the module app in build gradle file add this line

```
implementation project(":data")
```

For example, if you have 3 modules app, domain, and data in your app and you should implement all the modules in your app build.gradle file.

Comment: After trimming this answer a bit, I find it doesn't really give a lot of detail. If you have solved this, could you perhaps show some code or offer something a bit more concrete?

Comment: there is not such a specific code but I will edit the answer

Comment: I mean if you have more modules in  your app you should implement all modules that are participating in the injection from dagger.